# AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute '__dict__' but float64 works

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I am facing a very strange issue : `json.dumps(np.int64(1), default=lambda o: o.__dict__)` returns : `AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute '__dict__'`

While `json.dumps(np.float64(1), default=lambda o: o.__dict__)` returns correctly : `'1.0'`

Only difference is going from `int64` to `float64`... Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy.float64` inherits from `float`, so `json.dumps` handles instances like a regular float, and doesn't use your `default` callback.

`numpy.int64` doesn't inherit from `int` (and cannot reasonably do so due to conflicting semantics and memory layout), so `json.dumps` tries to use your `default` callback, which fails because `numpy.int64` instances don't have a `__dict__`.

Comment: Can you detail a bit more `(and cannot reasonably do so due to conflicting semantics and memory layout)`?

Comment: @Arcyno: `int` is an arbitrary-precision integer type with a variable-length memory layout and no overflow. `numpy.int64` is a fixed-precision integer type with an entirely different, fixed memory layout and operations that overflow. `numpy.int64` physically cannot inherit from `int` due to memory layout conflict, and it would be a bad idea anyway due to the differences in math behavior.